# Good way to represent odds ratios and p-values in R or Python

Tags: python, r, seaborn

Let's say I have n binary variables, and I want to compare them with n^2/2-n chi-square tests. As a result, I can get for each interaction an odds ratio (OR) and p-value. These can be shown like two separate nxn matrices (one for OR and one for p-value), but I would like to show them on a single informative plot.

A similar idea would be a [corrplot](https://www.google.com/search?q=corrplot%20r&sxsrf=ACYBGNRIzySHj-twEBLPmQXutvC7xAReuA:1575136785263&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLqLvkwZLmAhUMxqYKHba9CqIQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1280&bih=689&dpr=2) in R, but size would be comparable to OR, and p-value to color.

Is there any known package in R or Python that can plot something like this?
I tried seaborn in python:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = -np.log10(np.random.random((3,5)))
odds = (2*np.random.random((3,5))-1)

future_df = []
for i in range(p.shape[0]):
    for j in range(p.shape[1]):
        future_df.append([j+0.5,i+0.5,p[i,j],odds[i,j]])
df = pd.DataFrame(future_df, columns=["x","y","-log10(p)","OR"])

# Plotting
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
ax = sns.relplot(x="x", y="y", hue="-log10(p)", size="OR", data=df, 
                 palette="Reds", sizes=(0,10000), height=10, aspect=(odds.shape[1]/odds.shape[0])*1.5)
ax.ax.set(xlim=(0,odds.shape[1]))
ax.ax.set(ylim=(0,odds.shape[0]))
ax.ax.set(yticks=range(0,odds.shape[0]))

norm = plt.Normalize(0, 3)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Reds", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Modify old legend
handles, labels = ax.ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.ax.figure.colorbar(sm)
```

This starts doing what I intended, but I have two issues:
1) How to edit the old legend to spread out the values to make them visible?
2) Is there a way to explicitly control the size of the circles so I do not have to tweak manually? I would need the circles to be up to 1 unit in diameter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using some graphing libraries in python, I recommend this scatter plot library in python named seaborn:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/
If you have any questions feel free to ask me about seaborn!

Comment: Thanks! I tried, and I have edited my original question with seaborn Qs :)